# how to copy the register in hypothetical CPU ISA using assembly

Tags: assembly, instruction-set

Given following Instruction in a hypothetical CPU ISA with register space A-Z , write an assembly
program to copy N bytes from address A to address B

```
MOV C, 100 - Move a constant value 100 to register C
LDR A, Addr – Load Register A with contents of address Addr
STR B, Addr - Store the contents of register B to address Addr
CMP X, Y - Compare X & Y and set Equal/Less than and Greater than status flags
BEQ address – Branch/Jump to address, on status flag Equal is set
BGT address – Branch on greater than
BLT address – Branch on less than
```

Can any one please let me know how can this be done, i have no clue because without `inc`, `dec` and some arithmetic instructions, how can I proceed?

I do not need the code but any clue how can i proceed for this is appreciated in advance.

Comment: i have no clue because with out any arithmetic instructions how can i proceed.

Comment: I think that's not even a Turing-complete ISA

Answer (score 3):

What addressing modes do `ldr` / `str` support?  Can you `ldr C, 4(A)`?  If so, you can fully unroll the loop up to whatever displacement limit the addressing mode allows.

Still including the compares, though, unless you can treat `N` as a build-time constant (which would make sense because you're asked to write a program, not a function...)

e.g.

```
    cmp   N, 1
    blt   done
    ldr   C, 0(A)
    str   C, 0(B)

    cmp   N, 5       # registers are probably 4 bytes wide, if addresses are 32-bit
    blt   done
    ldr   C, 4(A)    # copy next word
    str   C, 4(B)

    cmp   N, 9
    beq   done
    ...
done:
```

With registers wider than 1 byte, it's impossible to copy only a single byte.  (With no ALU instructions to merge a byte into the old value of a word, and no byte store).

Assuming that registers are 4 bytes wide (because OP says it has 32-bit addressing), 4 bytes is the minimum we can copy.  If the machine allows unaligned addresses, we could copy any amount from 4 upward by increasing the addresses 1 byte at a time, but the code above always copies a multiple of 4 bytes.

If the machine only supports word-aligned load/store, overlapping the last word by 3 bytes wouldn't even be an option.

---

**Or you could implement INC with a fully-unrolled search for the next highest number, using MOV immediate and CMP/BEQ**.  (Or BLT / BGT for a binary search).

I'm inventing syntax for address-in-a-register on the assumption that A was supposed to be a register name, not a label

```
.copyloop:
    ldr    C, (A)
    str    C, (B)

    mov    D, 2
    cmp    A, 1
    beq    .found_A

    mov    D, 3
    cmp    A, 2
    beq    .found_A

    mov    D, 4
    cmp    A, 3
    beq    .found_A

    ...

 .found_A:
    mov    A, D       # presumably this is allowed, not only the mov-immediate form shown?

    # Then repeat that for B

    cmp    A, end_pointer   # end_pointer is a register holding a value you calculated somehow.
    blt  .copyloop
```

If your instruction-set is really that crippled, then your computer is *barely* programmable, and requires *massive* programs that enumerate every possible value a register might have.

You can use a binary search to make increment run in O(log(register_width)) time instead of O(value) time.

---

Perhaps you can store a lookup-table in memory that lets you implement `inc A` as  `ldr  A,  5000(A)`.  Except if memory is byte-addressable but words are wider than a byte, you need a scaled-index for the table, so this doesn't work.

Comment: It supports 32 bit addressing

Comment: @torban: So are registers 32-bit, or does `LDR` not support addresses in registers, only hard-coded addresses?  Anyway, this doesn't really change anything about about the answer.

Comment: yes, LDR loads had coded and also address of place into into destination register

Comment: If memory is byte-addressable but loads/stores are wider and unaligned, you can extract each byte of a register by storing it in memory, write a zero at the right location and load it back from the right address (assuming LE). This lets us split the inc32 problem into four inc8 problems. A similar technique can be used to extract the low byte of a register, allowing us to use 8-bit LUTs. Then inc8 can be implemented with a LUT and inc32 with four lookups.